Responsive Header Layout Issue in Bootstrap: Aligning Logo and Search Bar in Mobile View
I’m currently building a responsive header using Bootstrap. The layout works fine on the desktop version, but I’m having some alignment issues in the mobile view. Here’s a brief description of what I’m trying to achieve and the problems I’m facing:
The search bar is composed of two div elements: Input type="text" and Input type="submit"

-I want the input type="text" to take 80% of the available width and be aligned to the left.
The submit button should take the remaining 10% and be aligned to the right (we are left with a margin of 10%).

I tried using Bootstrap’s d-flex, justify-content, and text-end classes, but it’s not producing the desired layout.
Here is my current code:
<header class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
        <!-- Logo Column -->
        <div class="col-md-6 col-xs-12 d-flex">
            <img src="../logo_msp_Part.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
        </div>

        <!-- Spacer Column (Visible in Desktop only) -->
        <div class="col-3 d-none d-md-block"></div>

        <!-- Search Bar Columns -->
        <div class="col-2 justify-content-start">
            <form>
                <input type="text" class="form-control w-200" placeholder="Rechercher" id="rechercheInput">
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="col-1">
            <input type="submit" value="ok" class="btn btn-primary" id="ok_recherche">
        </div>
    </div>
</header>


I try adjusting the widths of the col-* classes to ensure that the columns are proportionate.
Used d-flex and justify-content-start/justify-content-end classes on the input fields.
Used w-100 and w-80 classes to try to control the widths of the text input and submit button.
Also I deleted my css concerning the header in media querys to avoid conflict over css and bootstrap.

I don't think you need an empty column; it's good to separate elements but it also restrict how much the elements could grow. There are two other possibilities:

Use offset-* to align the search element and button to the end (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.3/layout/columns/#offsetting-columns), it will create the space between the elements but it could lead to elements break out of their column in some dimensions. This option is good option if you are sure that your element will never overflow its parent container.

Give the parent of the search element a higher width of columns restricting the dimension of the search element. This is a good option if you know more or less the dimension of the search bar, it will be easier to adapt to smaller dimensions. This is what I used for the suggested solution


Firstly, I suppose you want to have together the button and search bar. The class input-group allow elements to be integrated together. If it is not the case, ignore the input-group that I used, although they will need to be under the same column to be placed together to the end.
I grouped the input search and button elements so they are in the same column and can be set to the end using the flex of the parent. The search element need to be set to inline-block and give a width to restrict it from using all the width and have both elements in the same line.
Lastly, to have a dimension in mobile phone, both elements, the containers of the logo and search column need to have a class of type col-*. If they do not have this class their width will be as they were given col-12.


#rechercheInput {
  width: 80%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#form {
  width: 300px;
}
<html lang="en" class="dark">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <title>Bootstrap demo</title>
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>
  <header class="container-fluid">
    <div class="row align-items-center">
      <!-- Logo Column -->
      <div class="col-4 col-md-6 col-xs-12 d-flex">
        <img src="../logo_msp_Part.png" alt="Logo" class="logo">
      </div>

      <!-- Search Bar Columns -->
      <div class="col-8 col-md-6 d-flex justify-content-end">
        <form id="form">
          <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class="form-control w-200" placeholder="Rechercher" id="rechercheInput">
            <input type="submit" value="ok" class="btn btn-primary" id="ok_recherche">
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </header>
  <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>
</html>




Thank for your answer !
My code ins now:
<div class="col-1 offset-xs-9 offset-sm-9 offset-md-0 d-xs-flex d-sm-flex justify-content-end justify-content-md-start">
     <input type="submit" value="ok" class="btn btn-primary" id="ok_recherche">
    </div>
   </div>
  </header>`
``

For an unknow reasron Iget the effect I want when my screen is beetwen 699px and 583px. But under that the spacing of my inputs does not correspond at all to my initial intention.

Hi! That's because of the width of the columns and the offset used. If you want in smaller devices to be each in each side, add offset-7 (or the number needed) to the button. I would also recomend to increase the col of the button to col-3 instead of col-1 so it includes the whole button. Take into account that for bootstrap each class is apply from smaller to bigger if there isn't a bigger class applied. Example: col-3 will affect in big screens if there isn't a col-lg-6 or something similar used. It also apply for offset.
